# Are the dual support bonuses already accounted for in the precombat window in FE:Awakening?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

This has been bugging me for a while. When I attack an enemy, and I get a dual support bonus (by standing adjacent to an ally, being paired up, etc, it doesn't seem to show up on the precombat damage calculations. That is to say, if I attack an enemy while standing adjacent to an ally, I may have a 70% hit chance, but when I attack the same enemy standing elsewhere, it still says 70%.

As such, I would be lead to believe that the hit and dodge chances are not included in the precombat screen. However, I was recently playing under this assumption and attacked an enemy with an 88% chance of hit, with no support ranks between me and my paired partner. To my surprise, I missed. If the hit bonus is not already included, then I should have a 98% hit chance. In another battle, under the same assumption, I allowed an enemy to attack me with a 20% chance to hit outside of forest. I first moved into a forest (+10 avoid?), and with Rank A support (hit+10, avo+10, crit+10, dodge+10), was still hit. If, as in my assumption, the avoid chance is not already included, then this enemy should have had a 0% hit chance on me when standing in forest.

The other part of this question, I suppose, is if I'm even calculating hit chances correctly. Does gaining +10 hit/avoid directly add/subtract from hit chance? If not, what is the formula for calculating hit chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support bonuses are most definitely already included in the calculations.  This is easy to check; move a character one space diagonally away from an enemy, and end his turn.  Move your other character next to him and the enemy, and check his chance to hit.  Cancel out, and move the character next to the enemy, but not the ally.  His stats will be lower, as the support bonus is not included now.

You are calculating it correctly; +10 hit/avoid is literally +10% to-hit or dodge.